# Mock article looking back at the development of artificial intelligence from the future

Tags: story-identification

This was a story someone posted online a few years ago. I don't believe it was ever in a book or magazine.

It was written like an academic paper or wikipedia article, looking back at AI, specifically about the one person's mind which booted up and experimented with in schools.

The idea was that you could keep it sane and talking for longer than any other mind, so it was the one that got used for research purposes. There were details about what happened if you told it how many years had passed or what changes had happened to the world.

The brains/personalities were referred too by code names, so if the person was called Mallory, the code might be MALLOR-1 or something. This is an example, if I could remember the code name I'd have searched for it!

I was sure I found this from a link in an answer on this very site, but it's difficult to search for given the trendiness of AI news these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Lena](https://qntm.org/mmacevedo) by qntm.

> *A series of landmark U.S. court decisions found that Acevedo did not have the right to control how his brain image was used, with the result that MMAcevedo is now by far the most widely distributed, frequently copied, and closely analysed human brain image.*
> ...
> Iterative experimentation beginning in the mid-2030s has determined that the ideal way to secure MMAcevedo's cooperation in workload tasks is to provide it with a "current date" in the second quarter of 2033. MMAcevedo infers, correctly, that this is still during the earliest, most industrious years of emulated brain research. Providing MMAcevedo with a year of 2031 or 2032 causes it to become suspicious about the advanced fidelity of its operating environment. Providing it with a year in the 2040s or later prompts it to raise complex further questions about political and social change in the real world over the past decade(s). Years 2100 onwards provoke counterproductive skepticism, or alarm.

Comment: That's the biscuit. Thanks.

Comment: @moopet - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)